# Gmail / Google Contacts: Is it possible to select Contacts in 2 specific Groups? Or Contacts in 1 specific Group and not another specific Group?

Tags: google-contacts

Question 1:

In Gmail / Google Contacts, let's say I have 12 contacts in Group A and 8 contacts in Group B.

4 contacts are in both Group A and Group B.

Is there a way I can filter to get results of only the contacts that are in both Groups?

(in this example there would be 4 contacts in the results)

Question 2:

Again, let's say I have 12 contacts in Group A and 8 contacts in Group B.

4 contacts are in both Group A and Group B.

Can I filter to get only the contacts that are in Group A and Not in Group B?

(in this example there would be 8 contacts in the results)

Comment: Unfortunately, this just doesn't seem possible. I can't even work out a kludgey way to do either.

Comment: Or if there's some software that integrates with Google Contacts, I'm interested...

Comment: Even selecting one group and scrolling for the other doesn't work very well because some of my contacts are members of lots of groups, so the group names shorten so I can't see them properly. Plus it's pretty time consuming, especially if I have a few filters to apply.

Answer (score 2):

## Short answer

Google Contacts search doesn't have the search operators to do such "search operations" [1].

## Remarks

From [2] could be taken several helpful keywords like `intersection` and `symmetric difference`.

## Alternatives

One alternative is to use spreadsheet functions to do set operations. See, from [3], [Set operations with New Google Sheets](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1KRrTSUIqJmqkJjdAnRDhFfYyilNUsIfNWZX5SwBK2xY/edit#gid=0). Reading [2] could be helpful to understand some terms used in the linked spreadsheet.

### Examples of Google Sheets formulas

Assume that the email addresses of contacts of Group A are in column A and email addresses of contacts of Group B are in column B

#### Intersection (question 1, contacts in both groups)

```
=FILTER($A$3:$A,MATCH($A$3:$A,$B$3:$B,0))
```

#### Symmetric Difference (question 2, contacts in Group A or in Group B but not in both)

```
=FILTER($A$3:$A,ISNA(MATCH($A$3:$A,$B$3:$B,0)))
```

## References

- [1] [Searching for contacts - Gmail Help](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/14002?hl=en)
- [2] [Set (Math) - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_(mathematics))

Answer (score -1):

This worked for me:
Select group 1, select all, assign a new group call "A and B"
do the same for group 2. 
Now they are all in group "A and B"

Comment: Isn't that just going to result in all the members of Group A _and_ Group B ending up in the new group? The OP wants the opposite.