# Is there a way to tag Google Contacts instead of grouping them?

Tags: gmail, google-contacts

Imagine that you have one group called 'London' that includes all your contacts in London.

Within 'London' you have subsets of groups such as football friends, etc.

With tags (or maybe filters) it would be easy to see find the union of 'London' and 'Footballers' but I can't figure out how to do it with Google Contact groups.

Only way it seems is by adding people into every applicable group which is time consuming.

Anyone have a way to do this?

Comment: There is no builtin feature in google contacts, but you can use the Notes field to add your tags. The Notes field is indexed so you can search its content

Comment: What is the difference between a 'group' and a 'tag'.  With either, you can identify a subset of contacts, and contacts can be members of multiple sets.  It doesn't really matter what you call it.  Google doesn't seem to have a feature to filter contacts the way you seem to want.

Comment: Thanks for the tip about using Notes. Seems like that could work but I hope they implement a more robust method soon.

Comment: Seems to be the same question as: [Gmail / Google Contacts: Is it possible to select Contacts in 2 specific Groups? Or Contacts in 1 specific Group and not another specific Group?](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/19258)

Comment: To answer #1:  With groups there is an implied OR.  I cannot set a message to JUST those people who are in London AND who are football fans.