# Gmail emailing the overlapping group

Tags: gmail, google-contacts

I have a few groups created in Google Contacts. For example, one group is by location, such as "NYC," another group is by association, such as "friends".

I want to email the people in these 2 groups that are both NYC **AND** friends. Right now if I type into the "To" line "NYC", all my NYC contacts come up, and if I type "friends", all my friends from around the country show up. I want to email the intersection of the 2. How do I do that without creating a third list?

Comment: Gmail/Google can't do a "union" of contact groups. The most practical solution is to create a third group that consists of the people who are in both groups. It's a pain, but all you can do with Gmail by itself.

Comment: This seems to be closely related to what you're trying to do: [Gmail / Google Contacts: Is it possible to select Contacts in 2 specific Groups? Or Contacts in 1 specific Group and not another specific Group?](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/19258/354)